# Is there a meta tag I can use to make sure my website scales down to fit the iPad viewport?

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile, meta-tags

Basically I have a site at the moment that is width 940px, at the moment I just need this site to be viewable on iPad whilst I begin adding in media queries to tailor the site for each device. Is there a meta tag I can use so that my site scales down when on iPad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

See [developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag/).

It sets the width and height to the device's width and height, sets the initial zoom to 1, and the maximum zoom to 1 (therefore making the page not zoomable).

**EDIT:** If you want the page to still be zoomable, remove `maximum-scale=1`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Why limit the users' ability to zoom the page - I personally hate it when websites do that.

Comment: @steveax - Yeah, I know how annoying that can be. `maximum-scale=1` should be removed for normal websites, but for app-like websites, it helps make it feel more like an app.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I use this in all my Mobile Sites.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad has a 1024x768 screen. You should be fine before adding in media queries.

Comment: yeah but in portrait mode it looks a bit off, was just hoping that when in that mode the site would scale down so the user sees all of it

Comment: understandable, the other answers suit your needs